# Write an expected value and mathematical dispersion for exponential distribution.

Tags: probability, expected-value

All I know is PDF for the exponential distribution $f(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x }, \text{if} x\ge 0 \text{ and } 0 \text{, if x < 0}$. Then how from there do I know the probability? If I guess and $\lambda$ is the amount of times the experiment is run then the expected value would be equal to $1$, but I really doubt it.

Comment: the dispersion is given by the variance divided by the expected value.

You can work out: 

Expected value  $\mu = \int_{0}^{\infty}x f(x)dx$.
Variance  $= \int_{0}^{\infty}x^2 f(x)dx - \mu^2$.

Comment: Note that a simpler way of computing $\mu$ is the so-called "Darth Vader rule, $\int_0^\infty (1-F(x))\ \mathsf dx$.

Answer (score 0):

The expected value is computed by
$$
\int_0^\infty (1-F(x))\ \mathsf dx = \int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda x} = \frac1\lambda.
$$
Adding on to George Dewhirst's comment, the dispersion is given by the variance divided by the expected value. We compute using integration by parts
$$
\mathbb E[X^2] = \int_0^\infty x^2 \lambda e^{-\lambda x} = \frac2{\lambda^2}.
$$
Hence the variance of $X$ is given by
$$\mathrm{Var}(X) = \mathbb E[X^2] = \mathbb E[X]2 = \frac2{\lambda^2} - \left(\frac1\lambda\right)^2 = \frac1{\lambda^2}.$$
It follows that the dispersion of $X$ is given by
$$
\frac{\mathrm{Var}(X)}{\mathbb E[X]} = \frac{\frac1{\lambda^2}}{\frac1\lambda} = \frac1\lambda.
$$